# Pass enum as generic to type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have `enum`:

```
enum A {
  a = 'a',
  b = 'b',
}
```

And a type:

```
type B<T = A> = {
   values: Record<T, string>; // error Type 'T' does not satisfy 
           //              the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.   

   // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.
}
```

Then I want to use it `const someVar: B<someEnum>;`.

Question: am I able to somehow pass `enum` as a generic to a `type`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you're ok with something like this:

```
type B<T extends A = A> = {
   values: Record<T, string>;
}
```

You won't be able to generalize enum though. Quoting [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#working-with-generic-type-variables):

> In addition to generic interfaces, we can also create generic classes.
> Note that it is not possible to create generic enums and namespaces.

Comment: `T extends PropertyKey = A` is enough, doesn't have to extend `A` specifically

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Enum keys of `A`, you need to extract them from the type it self.

Here is a sample on how you can achieve that:

```
enum A {
  a = 'a',
  b = 'b',
}

type B<T extends string = keyof typeof A> = {
   values: Record<T, string>;
  }

const object1 : B = {
values: {
  "a": "123",
  "b": "123"
}  
}
```